# Comparing the Jenkins plugins installed across instances

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I have 6 Jenkins hosts and one production Jenkins hosts where we are using close to 100 plugins. We want to make sure that all the instances have same plugins and their respective versions.

We tried below curl command to retrieve list of plugins used by particular host. We are trying to develop the utility to compare the plugin versions across all the hosts and give us report if any plugin is missing on production host.

```
curl 'https://<Jenkins url>/pluginManager/api/xml?depth=1&x‌​path=/*/*/shortName|‌​/*/*/version&wrapper‌​=plugins' | perl -pe 's/.*?<shortName>([\w-]+).*?<version>([^<]+)()(<\/\w+>)+/\1 \2\n/g'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete solution but you can definitely leverage Python libraries in order to compare the version incompatibilities OR missing plugins.

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests
import sys
from itertools import zip_longest
import itertools
from collections import OrderedDict
import collections
import csv

url = sys.argv[1].strip()
filename = sys.argv[2].strip()

response = requests.get(url+'/pluginManager/api/xml?depth=1',stream=True)
response.raw.decode_content = True
tree = ET.parse(response.raw)
root = tree.getroot()
data = {}
for plugin in root.findall('plugin'):
    longName = plugin.find('longName').text
    shortName = plugin.find('shortName').text
    version = plugin.find('version').text
    data[longName] = version
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        [f.write('{0},{1}\n'.format(key, value)) for key, value in data.items()]
```

Will give you the list of plugins in csv format!

Which later can be used to compare with another instance and all this can be achieved in a single python script.

Answer (score 0):

We do it like this in shell:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s <jenkins-url> list-plugins > <outputfile>
```

Then we work with that output for the different hosts to determine the differences.